# Winforms to UWP knowledge migration

Tags: winforms, class, methods, uwp

As a self-employed coder I'm struggling to move my winforms knowledge into uwp. It can take half an hour to even find the existence of StorageFile. Is there a resource out there that has a table that says if you use winforms.class.method() then take a look at uwp.classx.methodx().

(and ps.. what tags should I have applied to this question?)

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of. Plus, in many cases there aren't like for like comparisons so any such table would have massive gaps in it.
Instead you should start by learning the basics of the platform. [This MVA course](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/building-blocks-universal-windows-platform-16064) might be a good start.

Comment: I understand that. I was just looking for something that points me in the right direction when I want to do something like MessageBox.Show(). Thanks for the link. I am trying to migrate an app just as an exercise.